# Will Apple reject my app for using setStatusBarOrientation?

Tags: iphone, rotation, orientation, landscape, portrait

ViewController1 uses portrait orientation. ViewController2 uses landscape orientation. If I use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

Will my app get rejected? If I can't use this call, what is my other option? Simply rotating the images won't be sufficient since I need to use action sheets and alert prompts in the correct orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the class documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it would appear to be a documented part of the API and therefore valid to set.